# Capturar ID con php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Como capturar `ID` de una tabla con `prepared statement` en php y mysql para asignar esta Id que se capturó y agregarla a través de un `insert` como `foreign key` de la tabla siguiente. aquí el código:

```
<?php

//Tabla Cliente
$nom = $_POST["nombre"];
$ape = $_POST["apellido"];
$mail = $_POST["correo"];
$obs = $_POST["observacion"];
$con = $_POST["contrasena"];
$rut = $_POST["rut"];
$fono = $_POST["num_telefono"];

// Tabla Dirección
$calle = $_POST["calle"];
$num = $_POST["num_calle"];
$com = $_POST["comuna"];
$reg = $_POST["region"];



require('otraconexion.php');


    //Consulta Tabla Cliente

    $sql = "INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    $resultado = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sql);


$ok = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado,"ssssisi",$nom,$ape,$mail,$obs,$con,$rut,$fono);
$ok = mysqli_stmt_execute($resultado);
$fk = $sql->mysqli_insert_id();

//Consulta Tabla Direccion

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO direccion VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?)";
$resultado2 = mysqli_prepare($conexion, $sql2);

if(!$resultado2){
echo "Error al insertar.".mysqli_error($conexion);
}

$ok = mysqli_stmt_bind_param($resultado2,"sissi",$calle,$num,$com,$reg,$fk);
$ok = mysqli_stmt_execute($resultado2);



if($ok==false){

    echo"Error,";
}else{

    header("Location: ../Acceso/Indexp.php");

}

mysqli_stmt_close($resultado);


?>
```

Comment: no veo la necesidad dada tu pregunta de la etiqueta css

Comment: mysqli  tiene el método [**`insert_id`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.insert-id.php)  para esto, pero no es del todo seguro, sobre todo si la base de datos es multiusuario este método podría estar devolviéndote un dato erróneo debido a que luego de recuperar el valor otras inserciones pudieron haber ocurrido por otro lado. Quizá convendría manejar esto con transacciones.

Comment: Gracias por tu comentario amigo, pero me podrías aclarar eso de las transacciones?

Comment: Con transacciones tú puedes por ejemplo bloquear temporalmente la(s) tabla(s) mientras haces tu transacción para que nadie más la modifique mientras insertas los datos. Así sí, al usar `insert_id` estarás seguro de que es el último `id` porque nadie ha modificado la(s)  tablas mientras tuviste abierta y operativa tu transacción. Para más detalles [puedes leer esto en el Manual](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.transactions.php)

Comment: Echare un vistazo a las transacciones, pero encontré una mejor forma de hacer lo que quería con PDO así que postearé la respuesta yo mismo con ese método por si alguien necesita en un futuro lo mismo.

Comment: @A.Cedano `mysqli::$insert_id` es completamente seguro y no hay problemas de concurrencia con él, el motivo es que se aplica por cada hilo y conexión independientemente, por lo que no se ve afectado por otras conexiones de otros clientes, esto ha sido muy discutido.

Comment: @Xerif precisamente por lo que dices no es seguro. Si `cliente1` inicia una operación en la que *supuestamente*  obtiene el último id ingresado, digamos que es `71`; luego `cliente2` hace una inserción... ya el último id ingresado es `72`... si él necesita **absolutamente** el último id ingresado, ya la información que tiene no es verdadera, porque en su hilo él tiene que es el `71`, cuando en realidad es el `72`. O peor, imaginemos un programa mal escrito en el que se envían inserciones masivas fallidas y el id aumenta en 1 por cada inserción masiva... estaríamos ante una situación peor

Comment: @A.Cedano no estas entendiendo, lo que indicas no es cierto, si en un mismo Script php hay una sentencia y seguidamente  se llama a `mysqli::$insert_id` o si usamos pdo `PDO::lastInsertId` da igual que ese Script sea ejecutado simultáneamente por 1k de usuarios, nunca sucederá lo que dices, cada vez que ejecutas el archivo tu creas una conexión a la bd (`new mysqli()`), y `mysqli::$insert_id` recupera el id de la última sentencia de esa conexión específica, da igual que haya 1k más de ejecuciones simultáneas.

Comment: Es más puedes ver los códigos de cualquier ORM php que utilizan este método, puestos a prueba en grandes proyectos sin problemas.

Comment: @Xerif no has entendido mi comentario o no lo has leído bien. He dicho que si ahora mismo él recupera como último `id` el `71` él tiene ese valor como último id. Pero si después de él tener `$ultimo=71;` ocurren `n` inserciones o intentos de inserciones, el último id **real** será `71+n` no `71`. Si él a conitnuación hace una operación en la que debe usar el último id él va a usar el que tiene ya guardado que es `71`, pero resulta que el ùltimo id real es `71+n`.

Comment: @A.Cedano Pero es que no se trata se saber el ultimo id de la tabla, eso es irrelevante cuando ademas se intuye que utiliza autoincremental, se trata de saber el id del registro insertado, el OP no quiere saber cual es el id del ultimo registro insertado, lo que busca es saber el id del registro que acaba de iserta para utilizarlo como FK. Por este motivo la propiedad se llama `insert_id` (id de la insercion) o `lastInsertId` (id ultima insercion) y no algo como last_id (ultimo id).

Comment: Y si es para el caso siguiente: *usar ese último id para poner en relación **ese** registro que acaba de insertarse con otro registro de otra tabla* tampoco es seguro. ¿Qué ocurre si después de mi inserción otro usuario inserta otro registro y luego yo ejecuto `insert_id`? ¿Qué id se recupera realmente? Eso es algo que habría que probar en un escenario real. Las notas contributivas de los usuarios  sobre esta función en el Manual de PHP no son muy halagadores.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80447/discussion-between-xerif-and-a-cedano).

Comment: @A.Cedano __¿Qué ocurre si después de mi inserción otro usuario inserta otro registro y luego yo ejecuto insert_id?__ Cada script obtendria el id de su insercion, no hay problema de concurrencia en esto, por lo mismo que indiqe antes. Esta mas que probado en escenarios reales y con alta concurrencia. La unica nota contributiva a sobre dicha funcion en el manual que dice que podria fallar hace referencia a otra funcion similar pero diferente que nada tiene que ver con mysqli, por lo que carece de validez como prueba directamente.

Answer (score -1):

Aquí esta la solución para capturar la Id para tablas relacionadas con consultas preparadas, en este caso lo realice con PDO en php .

La conexion

```
<?php

try{
        $handler = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test','root','');
        $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
echo 'Sorry , DataBase Problem';
die();
}

if($handler == true)
{

}

    ?>
```

Formulario y Consultas:

```
 <?php
require('otraconexion.php');
//Table Cliente
$nom = $_POST["nombre"];
$ape = $_POST["apellido"];
$mail = $_POST["correo"];
$obs = $_POST["observacion"];
$con = $_POST["contrasena"];
$rut = $_POST["rut"];
$fono = $_POST["num_telefono"];

// Table Dirección
$calle = $_POST["calle"];
$num = $_POST["num_calle"];
$com = $_POST["comuna"];
$reg = $_POST["region"];

//Query Table Cliente
$sql = "INSERT INTO cliente VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$query = $handler->prepare($sql);
$query->execute(array($nom, $ape, $mail, $obs,$con, $rut, $fono));
$fk= $handler->lastInsertId();
echo $fk;

//Query Table Direccion
$sql2 = "INSERT INTO direccion VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?,".$fk.")";
$query = $handler->prepare($sql2);
$query->execute(array($calle, $num, $com, $reg));




?>
```